# Boost regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Does anyone know of any good tutorials on regular expressions using boost? I have been searching for a decent one, but it seems most are for people who know a little about regular expressions

Comment: Does not the one in the boost site itself help?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at sections 23.6, 23.7, 23.8, and 23.9 (pp. 830-849) of Bjarne's Stroustrup's new book: Programming: Principles and Practice using C++

Just like the rest of the book, these sections are very pedagogical and assume essentially zero background on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I always find the O'Reilly articles to be pretty helpful for many things. You could give [this](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/06/boostregex.html) a try. If the problem is that you're not too familiar with regular expressions, I'd read [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a primer on Regexes. Pay close attention to the Perl section, as many systems, including Boost, commonly support Perl-compatible Regexes.

Once you understand the basics, go for either the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or the aforementioned O'Reilly guide.